# upgraded .net, crystal - invalid resx file?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, resx

I've googled a lot but haven't found anything useful so far.
I upgraded an old VB .net1 application that got thrown at me to .net4.

Now when I compile I get the following error:

> Invalid Resx file. Could not load type
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.InternalEnterpriseLogonInfo,
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3300.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304 which is used in the
>   .RESX file.  Ensure that the necessary references have been added to
>   your project.

I Use the accompanying DLL files that came with the binary, which are Crystal 13.0.2 except for the two Enterprise DLL's that are 11.5.

I have no clue about what to do so any hint would be helpful!!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess it was all about mismatching DLL files. I forced the ones served with the application into the GAC and then it compiled.